# Treeview C# Click on a node for a text to appear

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, treeview, nodes

I have a treeview with multiple nodes (eg. a, b, c). If I click on "b", I want the word "Hello" to appear in the textbox.

I have a method like this:

```
private void treeList_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.layoutControlItem1.Text="hello";
}
```

The hello text is appearing even though I'm not clicking on a node. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see when it gets called

Comment: This can be simply solved by debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The best event to use is the `NodeMouseClick`.

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.layoutControlItem1.Text = e.Node.Tag.ToString();
}
```

The simplest way to get different massages for each node is to store them in the nodes' tags:

```
someNode.Tag = "Some Message";
```

Note that the `SelectionChanged` will fire more often than you want it to, including each time a selection is cleared..

If you need to include keyboard selection you should include a check for `treeView1.SelectedNode != null` in your code..

Comment: ye just people don't run in failures they don't want to
and u got right with a included check, but then you have to handle the SelectedNodeChanged Event too

Answer (score 0):

The first time you load your Form, `SelectedNodeChanged` Event will be fired because you assigning the values in `Instanciate()` or by code yourself.

I suggest you to use a global variable to store if the form is loaded by the `Load` Event:

```
private bool isLoad = false;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isLoad = true;
}

private void treeList_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(isLoad)
    {
        this.layoutControlItem1.Text="hello";
    }
}
```